# Error while running Karma on a project converted from CSS to SCSS

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-runner

I have converted an Angular 7 project which was originally created with CSS into SCSS.

As per the instructions in the official documentation, I included the following to *angular.json*

```
"schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "styleext": "scss"
        }
      }
```

and converted all CSS to SCSS and also changed all the style sheet references to SCSS. The application loads fine and did not encounter any problem until when I ran *ng test*. I am getting the following error when run Karma

```
08 06 2019 13:01:18.524:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.0.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
08 06 2019 13:01:18.525:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
08 06 2019 13:01:18.551:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeERROR in multi ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css' in 'E:\Workspace\angular\myproject'
resolve 'E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css' in 'E:\Workspace\angular\myproject'
  using description file: E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\package.json (relative path: ./src/styles.css)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css.tsx doesn't exist
      .mjs
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css.mjs doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css doesn't exist
[E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css]
[E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css.ts]
[E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css.tsx]
[E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css.mjs]
[E:\Workspace\angular\myproject\src\styles.css.js]
 @ multi ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css ./src/styles.css styles[1]
```

Even though I didn't completely understand this error message. It looks like Karma is still seeing the old CSS references somehow.

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Did you change the file paths in component decorators?

Comment: @ritaj Yes, I did!

Comment: `styles.css` you probable haven't change the reference in angular.json

Comment: @Gilsdav I have already done that.

Answer (score 0):

In your angular.json

change

```
"styles": [
      "src/styles.css"
],
```

to

```
"styles": [
      "src/styles.scss"
],
```

Comment: Have you done it in build and in test architect children ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, try deleting node modules of the project and re-install the dependencies.

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

and then

```
npm install
```